# Turned on publishing features, but can't save "Navigation" site settings?

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, access-denied, site-settings

I have a Team site where whenever I attempt to save the "Navigation", "Navigation Elements", or "Page Layout and Site Templates" Site Settings, I am directed to an "Access Denied" page. I'm a Site Collections Admin for the site, but at some point seem to have locked down my site settings.

Any known causes/ solutions for this issue?

**Edit:** I'm able to consistently reproduce the issue on a new site collection using the steps outlined [here](http://eimagine.com/how-to-display-the-master-page-link-in-site-settings-for-sharepoint-2013/), and the issue appears to be part of enabling the Publishing Features. I have not enabled/disabled any other site or collection features.

Comment: I suspect it's the post-save redirect rather than the save attempt that's causing the issue. Do the settings actually save when you click the Save button? Buried in the query string on the access denied page you should be able to see the url that redirected you there. Are you able to directly access that page?  What sorts of customizations are present on this site? Did something else happen on the site around the same time as this started happening?

Comment: The settings are not being saved. When I request access through the "Access Denied" page, it says I am requesting access to [Site Name]. This is a test zone where I've been playing around with a lot of settings, so there's a lot of random customization going on (i know this doesn't really help much).

Comment: There's a Site Collection Feature for "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" that is active. Could this be a cause for what I'm experiencing?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue on a separate site. It appears to happen when I enable the settings outlined here: http://eimagine.com/how-to-display-the-master-page-link-in-site-settings-for-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Your tags say "SharePoint Online". The linked article is for SharePoint 2013 OnPremises. Could you please confirm which version you are using?

Comment: SharePoint Online, the steps are consistent for how to enable the Master page in SPO :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a side effect of the scripting capabilities being turned off in your tenant.

Whenever you create a new tenant, the custom scripting capabilities are turned off by default. Now, it appears that even to change the Navigation, from say Structural navigation to managed navigation, or for any other changes in Navigation settings we need to enable the custom scripting capabilities.

You can lookup at the links mentioned below:

[Confusing Access Denied and managing Navigation Office 365](https://www.sharepointappie.nl/confusing-access-denied-managing-navigation-office365/)

[Allow or prevent custom script](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/allow-or-prevent-custom-script-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Now, to fix this issue, you need SharePoint admin rights.

After that, you can follow the steps mentioned below:

**Option 1**  - Using admin center UI

1) Go to the admin center. URL would be like -  `https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com`

2) Click on settings

3) In the settings page, in the `Custom Script` section, set the values to allow as in below image:

[image]

4) Click on OK to save the settings.

Now, you need to wait 24 hours for the scripting capabilities to be enabled. After that is turned on, you will be able to save the settings.

**Option 2 :** - Using SharePoint Online PowerShell

After opening the SPO PowerShell, run the below commands:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url "https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com"

Set-SPOSite "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/test" -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

Once you have executed these commands, it will be reflected immediately and you dont need to wait for 24 hours.

Download link - [SPO PowerShell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35588)

**PS** - You require SharePoint admin credentials for the above mentioned steps. Site Collection admin wont work.

Comment: I had IT check this setting and it is already set to allow. Additionally, I checked our root site collection, and with the settings enabled am able to save Navigation. Is there something I need to do to forward these permissions to my new site collection (part of the same tenant)?

Comment: Are you able to upload page layout or master page or anything else in the master page gallery of your site collection ? Do check that. Also, do try and get IT run the above PS script for your site collection.

Comment: I am not able to upload to the Style Library (I'm guessing this is what you meant by upload page layouts?) . I'll request that IT run the script and report back !

Comment: Couple more questions - How did you create this site collection ? Is it a modern team site or a classic team site ? Also, can you go to your `https://sitecollectionurl/_layouts/15/settings.aspx` page and open up the console and check what the web template is by typing `_spPageContextInfo.webTemplate` and tell me ?

Comment: The web template is "64" and the collection was created as a modern team site (sidebar: is there a way to create a classic team site?)

Comment: Ahhh that explains :) ... to create a classic team site, you need to ask your  admin to create it. Go to `https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com` and from then on click on create a new site collection with Team site (classic template). Also, can you tell me what you intend to do with Navigation?

Comment: Once the features are enabled and I'm unable to edit the Navigation Settings, I'm also unable to edit the quick launch and site navigation bars, meaning I can't even reorder the links.

Comment: can you drop by [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74499/discussion-between-vanblart-and-gautam-sheth) in the chat room ?